# Process vs. Thread with regards to using Queue()/deque() and class variable for communication and "poison pill"

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I would like to create either a Thread or a Process which runs forever in a While True loop.

I need to send and receive data to the worker in the form for queues, either a multiprocessing.Queue() or a collections.deque(). I prefer to use collections.deque() as it is significantly faster.

I also need to be able to kill the worker eventually (as it runs in a while True loop. Here is some test code I've put together to try and understand the differences between Threads, Processes, Queues, and deque ..

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque

class ThreadingTest(Thread):

    def __init__(self, q):
        super(ThreadingTest, self).__init__()
        self.q = q
        self.toRun = False

    def run(self):
        print("Started Thread")
        self.toRun = True
        while self.toRun:
            if type(self.q) == type(deque()):
                if self.q:
                    i = self.q.popleft()
                    print("Thread deque: " + str(i))
            elif type(self.q) == type(Queue()):
                if not self.q.empty():
                    i = self.q.get_nowait()
                    print("Thread Queue: " + str(i))

    def stop(self):
        print("Trying to stop Thread")
        self.toRun = False
        while self.isAlive():
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Stopped Thread")

class ProcessTest(Process):

    def __init__(self, q):
        super(ProcessTest, self).__init__()
        self.q = q
        self.toRun = False
        self.ctr = 0

    def run(self):
        print("Started Process")
        self.toRun = True
        while self.toRun:
            if type(self.q) == type(deque()):
                if self.q:
                    i = self.q.popleft()
                    print("Process deque: " + str(i))
            elif type(self.q) == type(Queue()):
                if not self.q.empty():
                    i = self.q.get_nowait()
                    print("Process Queue: " + str(i))

    def stop(self):
        print("Trying to stop Process")
        self.toRun = False
        while self.is_alive():
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Stopped Process")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    t1 = ProcessTest(q)
    t1.start()

    for i in range(10):
        if type(q) == type(deque()):
            q.append(i)
        elif type(q) == type(Queue()):
            q.put_nowait(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    t1.stop()
    t1.join()

    if type(q) == type(deque()):
        print(q)
    elif type(q) == type(Queue()):
        while q.qsize() > 0:
            print(str(q.get_nowait()))
```

As you can see, t1 can either be ThreadingTest, or ProcessTest. Also, the queue passed to it can either be a multiprocessing.Queue or a collections.deque.

ThreadingTest works with a Queue or deque(). It also kills run() properly when the stop() method is called.

```
Started Thread
Thread deque: 0
Thread deque: 1
Thread deque: 2
Thread deque: 3
Thread deque: 4
Thread deque: 5
Thread deque: 6
Thread deque: 7
Thread deque: 8
Thread deque: 9
Trying to stop Thread
Stopped Thread
deque([])
```

ProcessTest is only able to read from the queue if it is of type multiprocessing.Queue. It doesn't work with collections.deque. Furthermore, I am unable to kill the process using stop().

```
Process Queue: 0
Process Queue: 1
Process Queue: 2
Process Queue: 3
Process Queue: 4
Process Queue: 5
Process Queue: 6
Process Queue: 7
Process Queue: 8
Process Queue: 9
Trying to stop Process
```

I'm trying to figure out why? Also, what would be the best way to use deque with a process? And, how would I go about killing the process using some sort of stop() method.

Comment: I can kill the process in the following way:
Create another class variable: self.killQ = Queue():
Instead of while toRun, I can do while self.killQ.empty():
In the stop() method I can append a dummy object to the Queue, like self.killQ.put_nowait(0)

But ... why won't a class variable like toRun work? Does it have something to do with the assignment of self.toRun = False in the stop() method?

Comment: Another observation with the Process. I can use a deque within the process to pass stuff around, and it works fine. I just can't use a deque to communicate between processes (main, and ProcessTest in this example).

Comment: As an aside, its generally a bad practice to check if a `Queue` is empty before consuming from it. It's susceptible to race conditions, since if multiple threads are reading from a `Queue`, it could become empty between the time you check its size and when you actually try to `get` from it. In this case, I think you're better off just calling `q.get()` directly. That way you're not constantly looping and therefore using CPU in the child while you wait for something to be in the `Queue`.

Comment: I would also remove the `while self.is_alive: time.sleep(0.1)` call in `stop`, since you're calling `join()` on the process/thread right afterwards. You might as well just call `join()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use a `collections.deque` to pass data between two `multiprocessing.Process` instances, because `collections.deque` is not process-aware. `multiprocessing.Queue` writes its contents to a `multiprocessing.Pipe` internally, which means that data in it can be enqueued in once process and retrieved in another. `collections.deque` doesn't have that kind of plumbing, so it won't work. When you write to the `deque` in one process, the `deque` instance in the other process won't be affected at all; they're completely separate instances.

A similar issue is happening to your `stop()` method. You're changing the value of `toRun` in the main process, but this won't affect the child at all. They're completely separate instances. The best way to end the child would be to send some sentinel to the `Queue`. When you get the sentinel in the child, break out of the infinite loop:

```
def run(self):
    print("Started Process")
    self.toRun = True
    while self.toRun:
        if type(self.q) == type(deque()):
            if self.q:
                i = self.q.popleft()
                print("Process deque: " + str(i))
        elif type(self.q) == type(Queue()):
            if not self.q.empty():
                i = self.q.get_nowait()
                if i is None:  
                    break  # Got sentinel, so break
                print("Process Queue: " + str(i))

def stop(self):
    print("Trying to stop Process")
    self.q.put(None)  # Send sentinel
    while self.is_alive():
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("Stopped Process")
```

**Edit:**

If you actually do need `deque` semantics between two process, you can use a [custom `multiprocessing.Manager()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers) to create a shared `deque` in a `Manager` process, and each of your `Process` instances will get a `Proxy` to it:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
from collections import deque

SyncManager.register('deque', deque)

def Manager():
    m = SyncManager()
    m.start()
    return m

class ProcessTest(Process):
    def __init__(self, q):
        super(ProcessTest, self).__init__()
        self.q = q
        self.ctr = 0

    def run(self):
        print("Started Process")
        self.toRun = True
        while self.toRun:
            if self.q._getvalue():
                i = self.q.popleft()
                if i is None:
                    break
                print("Process deque: " + str(i))

    def stop(self):
        print("Trying to stop Process")
        self.q.append(None)
        while self.is_alive():
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Stopped Process")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Manager()
    q = m.deque()
    t1 = ProcessTest(q)
    t1.start()

    for i in range(10):
        q.append(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    t1.stop()
    t1.join()

    print(q)
```

Note that this probably isn't going to be faster than a `multiprocessing.Queue`, though, since there's an IPC cost for every time you access the `deque`. It's also a much less natural data structure for passing messages the way you are.